# Probability of picking all white marbles?

Tags: probability

Consider that you have a drawer with n marbles of various colors. There are 5 white colored marbles.

You grab k marbles from the drawer, where k <= n. What is the probability you find all 5 white marbles in the n marbles you grabbed?

How do I go about solving this? I think the probability of any marble being white is 5/n but don't know where to go from there.

Comment: In the second choose function, do you mean ((n-k) choose (k-5))?

Comment: Otherwise - couldn't the denominator of the choose be greater than the numerator of the choose?

Comment: One more follow up - why is the numerator n-k and not n-5?

Comment: I am having a bad day. Will delete, write a correct comment.

Comment: There are $\binom{n}{k}$ equally likely ways to pick $k$ marbles. There are $\binom{5}{5}\binom{n-5}{k-5}$ ways to pick $5$ white and the rest non-white.

Answer (score 0):

A little help:

$$ P(n, k < 5) = 0 $$
$$ P(n, k = 5) = \sum_{i=0}^4 \frac{5 - i}{n - i} $$
$$ P(n, k = n) = 1 $$

Only the very first marble you pick has a $\frac5n$ chance of being white.

The answer'd be something like:

$$ P(n, k) = \frac{f(n, k)}{\left(^n_k\right)} $$ with $f(n, k)$ being all different sets of k that contain your white marbles.